# Can I extend the catalog view of IGC to include Web Services information

Tags: ibm-information-server, ibm-governance

I would like to include Web Services within the IGC Catalog, and attach those Services to Terms to extend their meaning, or Rules to define their specification or requirement.  Additionally, allow users to view their usage or dependency for impact analysis.  Could I design my own Asset Types in the Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

This is an example when we use the Open IGC Framework to model the whole ODI - https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/creation-of-new-bundle-on-infosphere-information-governance-catalog/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer you can also take a look at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21699130 (there are also links to further online resources).